# print variable value outside the for each loop without page refresh

Tags: php, jquery-mobile, foreach

Below is my code when i store date in session variable from foreach loop and print in header portion in jquery mobile page it print date but after refresh page when i run page first time  it could not print date.how to solve this problem please help me.

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <body>
    <div data-role="page" id="index" data-theme="c">
    <div data-theme="b" data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
  <?php
    print"<div>"; 
    print"<pre style=text-align:center;>";
        echo 'Last Updated On:- '.$_SESSION['causedate'];
    print"</pre>";
print" </div>";
 ?>
    </div>

<div data-role="content">

<?php

function curlUsingGet($url, $data)
{

if(empty($url) OR empty($data))
 {
 return 'Error: invalid Url or Data';
 }

            $fields_string = '';
            foreach($data as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.urlencode($value).'&'; }
            rtrim($fields_string,'&');

             $urlStringData = $url.'?'.$fields_string;
            $cookie= "cookie.txt";
            $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT , "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; Windows NT 6.1)");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION,true);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT,true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$urlStringData);

            $return = curl_exec($ch);

            $arrel = explode('|',$return);

    foreach($arrel as $val)
    {
     $new_el=explode('~',$val);
     echo $new_el[0]; 
    echo $new_el[2];
    echo $new_el[3];
    echo $new_el[4];
    echo $new_el[1]; 

    $_SESSION['date'] = $new_el[6];

}

curl_close($ch);

}
$data = array('u' =>$_SESSION['councel']);
echo curlUsingGet('url',$data);
 ?>
</div>
    <div data-theme="b" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
     <div>
 <pre style="text-align:center">Dan Electronics</pre>
</div>  
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the session variables:

```
<?
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['causedate'])) $_SESSION['causedate'] = ""; /* something */
```